# Send email based on dropdown menu selection (mysql column update/status change)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to send an email whenever a different selection is posted to the database.

```html
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group row <?php echo (!empty($lotstatus_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <label class="form-control-label">Status</label>
                                <select class="form-control" value="<?php echo $lotstatus; ?>" id="lotstatus" name="lotstatus">
                                <option value="Executed">Executed</option>
                                        <option value="Not Interested" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Not Interested'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Not Interested</option>
                                        <option value="Hold" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Hold'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Hold</option>
                                        <option value="Title Ordered" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Title Ordered'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Title Ordered</option>
                                        <option value="Vetting" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Vetting'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Vetting</option>
                                        <option value="Survey Ordered" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Survey Ordered'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Survey Ordered</option>
                                        <option value="Lean Search Ordered" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Lean Search Ordered'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Lean Search Ordered</option>
                                        <option value="Clear to Closed" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Clear to Closed'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Clear to Closed</option>
                                        <option value="Closed" <?php if($row["lotstatus"]=='Closed'){ echo "selected";} ?>>Closed</option>
                                </select>
```

So, when a user updates the status, an email is sent out saying "this record was updated from 'previous status' to 'new status'. I have this under my prepared statement:

```html
if(isset($_POST["lotstatus"]) && !empty($_POST["lotstatus"])){ 
    $lotstatusPost = $_POST['lotstatus']; 
    $lotstatus = $row['lotstatus'];
    $streetnumber = $row['streetnumber'];
    $streetname = $row['streetname'];

    if($lotstatus != $lotstatusPost) {
        $email='al@gmail.com';
        $subject = "Lot Status Change";
        $message =$streetnumber. ' '. $streetname. ' '. 'Lot Status has changed from'.' '. $lotstatus. ' '. 'to'.' '. $lotstatusPost;
        $headers = "From: My Company"; 
        
        mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers); 
            //mail successfully sent
        
    }
}
```

No errors. It's just not sending. Or if I don't check if it isset, it sends when I land on the update page w/o the _POST field. 
HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Store the original value into a hidden field on your form i.e.

```
<input type-'hidden' name='oldLostStatus' value="<?php echo $row["lotstatus"];?>">
```

Then when processing - pick up the old value i.e.

```
$lotstatus = $_POST['oldLotStatus'];
```

Also your code:

```
$streetnumber = $row['streetnumber'];
$streetname = $row['streetname'];
```

wont work because your are not getting the values from the form - use

```
$streetnumber = $_POST['streetnumber'];
$streetname = $_POST['streetname'];
```

Comment: Thanks! comparing the old value to the new Post value worked!